# mybatis relation one to one, send multi parameters

Tags: caching, mybatis, one-to-one

I'm using mybatis, and I have a one to one relation, but I wanna send multiple parameters, here is my code:

```
@Mapper
public interface ParentMapper {
    @Select("select o.id, o.name, o.key from parent o where o.key=#{key}")
    @Result({
        @Result(column = "id", property = "id")
        @Result(column = "name", property = "name")
        @Result(column = "id", property = "child", one=@One(select = "getChild"))
    })
    List<Parent> getParents(@Param("key") String key, @Param("childKey") String childKey);

    @Select("select id, childName, childKey from child where parentId=#{parentId} and childKey = #{childKey}")
    Child getChild(@Param("parentId")String parentId, @Param("childKey") String childKey);
}
```

as you can see, logically, I fetch a list of Parent, and then I send 2 parameters: parent's id, childKey, to get child. 
But how can i make it happen use @One annotation?

Comment: The snippet is false: embedding annotation is `@Results` commas are missing between each row of `@Result`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020095/composite-keys-in-mybatis-collection-mappings). 
You must specify both column in the mapping result.
Although they use XML, it could be transposable in annotation-based mapping. Although I have failed to do it so far.
Anyway, I don't see what the 2nd column would be.

Furthermore, If you don't use lazy loading: `@One(fetchType=FetchType.LAZY, select="getChild")`, then I don't see the point of an N+1 select.
You'd better SQL JOIN and have the whole structure built with a single query.